# Create a Personal Campaign Page links to a page that does not exist

Tags: wordpress, contribution-page

When I enable the "Create a Personal Campaign" within the contribution page manager, the link to share to create a personal campaign page is provided at the bottom of the contribution page manager as shown here:
[image]

The link provided leads to a Page Not Found error:

This is the link https://lofcenter.org/civicrm?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contribute/campaign&action=add&reset=1&pageId=1&component=contribute

This is the resulting error:

[image: Sorry No Posts Matched Your Criteria]

Any suggestions on how to proceed trouble shooting this error?

Answer (score 1):

Please try to create a new page in wordpress and then include CiviCRM component in the wordpress page and then please try the same

Comment: I dropped the component into a page and the link does work.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a related issue. Here's a link to a page I created in Wordpress where I've dropped 2 x short code entries for events created in civievent.  https://lofcenter.org/events/   But if you click on any of the "find out more..." links they point to a page that does not exists.

Comment: so you have created a page called events and you wanted to display all the civicrm event in the same page ? if that is the case try creating page wordpress page for each event and use those Link in events page